# Trace information doesn't appear at the end of the page

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I'm trying to enable tracing in an ASP.NET application and have followed the MSDN page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x5wc973(v=vs.85).aspx

I have the trace element in my web.config file:

```
<trace enabled="true" pageOutput="true" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false"/>
```

But I don't get any trace information at the end of any pages. What could cause this?

Comment: Is it possible that you have the 'trace' attribute on the Page directive of the individual page with its value set to 'false'?

Answer (score 0):

If you view the page source do you see any markup related to the trace at the bottom of the page? Maybe you have some CSS rules that hide the output?

You could also try enabling the trace per page using the following directive -

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Trace="true" TraceMode = "SortByCategory" Inherits  = "System.Web.UI.Page" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" %>
```

You can also try viewing the output from the standard tracing URL - ~/trace.axd

Comment: No, there is no markup in the page source either. Good thinking though! Per page trace doesn't work either, but trace.axd does show a list of requests - number, time, file... but the "view details" links don't work.

Answer (score 0):

My powers of psychic debugging tell me that you have an ASP.net web-site, and not an ASP.net application.

**Note**: Since i don't know how, or want to learn, how to create an ASP.net **application** out of my ASP.net **web-site** - i can't test my theory.

---

There are plenty of things that don't work in a web-site. For example [i am cursing and swearing that ASP.net web-sites don't support conditional defines.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397158/how-to-add-a-define-to-an-asp-net-solution)