# How to add a define to an ASP.net solution?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, conditional-compilation

i can add a `define` to a **WinForms** project through the *Project Properties*:

[image]

How do i add a `define` to an **ASP.net** solution?

---

**Update**: Here's what Visual Studio 2010 looks like when working in an ASP.net solution:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution Explorer > WebApplicationProject (Name of your Web Application) > Properties > Build:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is **Web Application**?

Comment: i see your edits. Rather than going back and forth, i just updated my question with a screenshot of Visual Studio. Use *Windows Snipping Tool* Point to **Web Application** in my screenshot and add to your answer. Please :)

Comment: Ok got it you are using website instead of ASP.Net Web Application Project. You should use "ASP.Net Web Application Project" instead of Website. Microsoft recommends using "ASP.Net Web Application Project"

Comment: Reading [Web Application Projects versus Web Site Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx), Microsoft notes there are pros and cons to a web application. Some of the cons of a web-application that are show stoppers: *You want to be able to update individual files in production by just copying new versions to the production server, or by editing the files directly on the production server.*, *You do not want to have to explicitly compile the project in order to deploy it.*, *You like to keep your source code on the production server*.

Comment: If ASP.net cannot define defines that's fine - it's the answer. Worst case i'll fork the project, and create a custom version of source-code files tailored for my defines.  But i assume asp.net web-site solution **can** contain defines.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `compilerOptions` attribute of the `compiler`v element in `web.config`? Like so:

```
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" 
            extension=".cs" 
            warningLevel="4" 
            type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
            compilerOptions="/define:TRACE">
            <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
            <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
        </compiler>
....
```

Should do the trick I think...