# How to trace Debug messages in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

**Short version:** i've added

```
 <system.web>
   <system.diagnostics>
      <trace>
         <listeners>
            <add name="WebPageTraceListener" type="System.Web.WebPageTraceListener, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
         </listeners>
      </trace>
   </system.diagnostics>
```

to my web-site's **web.config** file, but Visual Studio complains:

> Unrecognized configuration section system.web/system.diagnostics.

How do i make Visual Studio (2010 (Professional (Windows 7 (64-bit)))) not complain?

---

### Background

Microsoft explains that in ASP.net you use the `TraceContext.Warn` method to add tracing information to the trace output, e.g.:

```
Page.Trace.Warn("Starting up - da shield");
```

Tracing is then [enabled when you enable tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx):

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <trace enabled="true" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

or when you enable tracing:

```
<%@ Page ... Trace="true" ... %>
```

Tracing is then enabled on the bottom of the page:

[image]

---

### But what about System.Diagnostics tracing?

That's well and good for ASP.net code, but *business objects* don't use **`System.Web.UI.TraceContext`** for tracing, they use `System.Diagnostics.Trace`:

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceWarning("No giving up General Jar Jar. Yousa tink of someting");
```

Microsoft explains that you **can** route `Diagnostics` tracing through `Web` tracing using:

> ### [Walkthrough: Integrating ASP.NET Tracing with System.Diagnostics Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0ectfxd.aspx)
>
> **Routing All Tracing Output to the Web Form**
>
> To route Trace messages to an ASP.NET Web page, you must add a WebPageTraceListener object.
>
> Place the following code in your Web.config file after the **<system.web>** section.
>
> ```
> <system.diagnostics>
>   <trace>
>     <listeners>
>        <add name="WebPageTraceListener" 
>             type="System.Web.WebPageTraceListener, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
>     </listeners>
>   </trace>
> </system.diagnostics>
> ```

Except that Visual Studio complains:

> Unrecognized configuration section system.web/system.diagnostics.

Worse Than Failure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<system.diagnostics>` should be the child of `<configuration>` not `<system.web>`, so something like:

```
<configuration>
...
 <system.diagnostics>
  <trace>
    <listeners>
       <add name="WebPageTraceListener" 
            type="System.Web.WebPageTraceListener, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
    </listeners>
  </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Hope I understood the issue right and this helps.

Comment: It stops error Visual Studio was throwing (that was my bad, i read *after `system.web`* to be after `<system.web>` rather than after `</system.web>`). Unfortunately, it turns out that ASP.net web-sites do not support the [`WebPageTraceListener`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944714/trace-information-doesnt-appear-at-the-end-of-the-page/11434542#11434542)

Comment: I guess you're left to the plain old txt file